# jQuery not hiding div but DOM is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm fairly new to jQuery so please go easy on me because I think this is a simple mistake.

I have a website that is showing a multiple choice quiz. Each question can have between 2 and 4 options. If blank options will always be coded as "###" in the question array, so what I would like to do is simply hide the div that contains the text "###".

I have the following (simplfied) HTML layout:

```
<div class="row" name="row1">

 <div class="col-xs-12 jumbotron text-center" id="ans1Text" onclick="checkAnswer1()">

   Text Goes Here
</div>
</div>


<div class="row" name="row2">

 <div class="col-xs-12 jumbotron text-center" id="ans2Text" onclick="checkAnswer2()">

   Text Goes Here
</div>
</div>


<div class="row" name="row3">

 <div class="col-xs-12 jumbotron text-center" id="ans3Text" onclick="checkAnswer3()">

   Text Goes Here
</div>
</div>


<div class="row" name="row4">

 <div class="col-xs-12 jumbotron text-center" id="ans4Text" onclick="checkAnswer4()">

   Text Goes Here
</div>
</div>
```

At the bottom of the page I call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                        setupQuiz();
                          });
```

Then `setupQuiz` calls `setupQuestion()`:

```
function setupQuestion()
{
var r = Math.random();

$('#qnum').text(questionNumber.toString() + "/" + (nQuestions-1).toString());
$('#timeRemaining').text(timePerQuestion);


$('#questionText').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].q);
if (r < 0.25){
    $('#ans1Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].correct);
    $('#ans2Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].incorrect1);
    $('#ans3Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].incorrect2);
    $('#ans4Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].incorrect3);
}
else if (r>=0.25 && r <0.5){
    $('#ans2Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].correct);
    $('#ans1Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].incorrect1);
    $('#ans4Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].incorrect2);
    $('#ans3Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].incorrect3);
}
else if (r>=0.5 && r < 0.75){
    $('#ans3Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].correct);
    $('#ans4Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].incorrect1);
    $('#ans2Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].incorrect2);
    $('#ans1Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].incorrect3);
}
else
{
    $('#ans4Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].correct);
    $('#ans1Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].incorrect1);
    $('#ans2Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].incorrect2);
    $('#ans3Text').text(quizquestions[questionNumber-1].incorrect3);
}

if ( $('#ans1Text').text().indexOf("###") !=-1 )
{
    $('#row1').hide(); 
    console.log("1");  
}

if ( $('#ans2Text').text().indexOf("###") !=-1 )
{
    $('#row2').hide(true); 

    console.log("2"); 
}

if ( $('#ans3Text').text().indexOf("###") !=-1)
{
    $('#row3').hide(true); 

    console.log("3"); 
}

if ( $('#ans4Text').text().indexOf("###") !=-1)
{
    $('#row4').hide(true);

    console.log("4");  
}


if(questionTimer != null)
{
    clearInterval(questionTimer);
    questionTimer = null;
}



questionTimer = setInterval(tick, 1000);

}
```

All of the code to setup question text works perfectly well, and the console logs the correct number, but the correct div is never hidden! I am lost on this, and I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with my code, I don't think it liked using `$('#row1')` because that was only a name and not an id.

Also taking out the argument to hide helped, but I needed to have an else to show it again the next time around:

```
if ( $('#ans1Text').text().indexOf("###") !=-1 )
{
    $('#ans1Text').hide(); 
    console.log("1");  
}
else
{
    $('#ans1Text').show();
}

if ( $('#ans2Text').text().indexOf("###") !=-1 )
{
    $('#ans2Text').hide();; 

    console.log("2"); 
}
else
{
    $('#ans2Text').show();
}

if ( $('#ans3Text').text().indexOf("###") !=-1)
{
    $('#ans3Text').hide();; 

    console.log("3"); 
}
else
{
    $('#ans3Text').show();
}

if ( $('#ans4Text').text().indexOf("###") !=-1)
{
    $('#ans4Text').hide();;

    console.log("4");  
}
else
{
    $('#ans4Text').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use hide() instead of hide(true).

jQuery is trying to turn true into a "time" estimate for hiding.
in other words. it's trying to figure out how fast to hide your div.

Either put a number there like 2000 (2 seconds). 
Or nothing at all hide(); (default speed)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use css here:

```
$('#row2').css("display", "none");
```

instead of

```
$('#row2').hide(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call just .hide() without passing in true.